# Laravel - catching a 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have this update function I'm aware the `findOrFail` call returns a model not found exception sent to the user. Is there a way you can add some code to catch this if an ID is not found or does the call do that for me? Here is the function it needs applying too.

```
public function update(string $id)
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();

    $this->film = Film::findOrFail($id);

    if (!$this->hasFilm()) {
        abort(400, "You don't have a film configured");
    }

    $this->validation();

    $this->transaction();

    return $this->film->toJson();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually do a `try {...} catch {...}` in that function.

If you want to do that for all the places that will throw `ModelNotFoundException`, you can look at `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and change the `render` method

However, if you see you're doing this for many other exceptions, it's better if you create your own exceptions, as documented in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#renderable-exceptions)

Comment: am i only doing it for this function, so it might be ideal to just add a try catch

Comment: Johann's answer is good to. Pick whichever you like. Both should be good for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw a custom abort when the `PodcastProfile` is not found, just for this method, you can do something like:

```
public function update(string $id)
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();

    $this->podcastProfile = PodcastProfile::find($id);

    if (!$this->podcastProfile) {
        abort(400, "You don't have a podcast profile configured");
    }

    $this->validation();

    $this->transaction();

    return $this->podcastProfile->toJson();
}
```

If the `PodcastProfile` is not found it'll be empty, and then you'll get the `abort(400)`